# Data pushed to google tag manager but shown undefined in google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I used below code to push data to google Tag manager, it works fine but show undefined in google analytic.

I followed steps from http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/form-field-timing-with-google-tag-manager/#gref

Following is code used to fire event'

```
function gapRecordAnalytics(page_load_start, pageName)
{
   window.dataLayer.push({
          'event' : 'LTTiming',
          'timingCategory' : 'GTM1_TEST',
          'timingVariable' : 'sfsdfsdfsdfsfd',
          'timingLabel' : '10.10.16.46',
          'timingValue' : 7000
    });

}
```

Attached is screenshot from browser console.
[image]

Below is screenshot of tags page
[image]
Variables are the custom JavaScript variables.

Comment: Did you add the trigger and the tag in GTM as described in the post you referenced?

Comment: Can you please post screenshots of your GTM tag/variable/triggers? I tested it on my side and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: updated answer with tag screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved, there was issue in selecting variable type.

Check all variable used on JavaScript are case sensitive.
As you are using Data Layer to push data to google analytics, other variable type should be data Layer variable.

[Reference link](http://greatym.com/forum/thread/6/google-tag-mager-pushed-undefined-to-google-analytics/)